# The Predual of a von Neumann algebra

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ $\subseteq$ $B(H)$ be a *von Neumann algebra*. I am wondering how does 
$M_*$ sit inside $B(H)_*$ upto isometry. 
Note - $M_*$ denotes the predual of $M$.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it does.  The natural map of which the inclusion $\iota : M \to B(H)$ is the dual would be a projection of $B(H)_*$ onto $M_*$.  Namely, each element of $B(H)_*$, considered as an ultraweakly continuous linear functional on $B(H)$, maps to its restriction to $M$.

Comment: but every normal functional on $M$ can be extended to a normal functional on  $B(H)$, so you can say that $M_*$ is a quotient of $B(H)_*$. Not that I think this is a useful point of view.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, could you, please, give a reference for this? I mean for the fact that the map $B(H)_*\to M_*$ is surjective.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: Theorem 7.1.12 in Kadison-Ringrose. Every normal state on $M$ is spatial, so it extends trivially to a normal functional on $B(H)$. Every $\sigma$-weakly continuous functional is a linear combination of normal states.

Answer (score 3):

Robert is right.

To provide a counter-example, consider any embedding $L_\infty[0,1]\subset B(L_2[0,1])$. Certainly, $L_1[0,1]$ is the (unique) predual of $L_\infty[0,1]$. Now, the predual of $B(L_2[0,1])$ is a (separable) dual of the algebra of compact operators, hence it has [the Radon–Nikodym property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_property) (and this property passes to closed subspaces). On the other hand it is well-known that $L_1[0,1]$ lacks the Radon–Nikodym property. This can be easily generalised to the following setting.

> Suppose that $\mathcal{M}\subset B(H)$ is an infinite-dimensional, finite von Neumann algebra. Then $\mathcal{M}_*$ does not embed into $B(H)_*$ as a Banach space.

See Chapter VII of

> J. Diestel and J. J. Uhl Jr., *Vector Measures*, volume 15 of Math. Surveys. AMS, Providence, RI, (1977).

for an excellent treatment of the Radon–Nikodym property.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the inclusion $\iota:M_*\to B(H)_*$ is an isometry. Taking dual, $\pi=\iota^*$ forms a w*-w* continuous *-homomorphism from $B(H)$ onto  $M$.  It implies that, $M$ is isomorphic to $B(H)/K$ where $K$ is a two-sided ideal in $B(H)$.

For example if $H$ is separable then $M$ should be (isomorphic to) the Calkin algebra. Firstly, the Calkin algebra is not von Neumann algebra. Secondly, if the assertion is true then there is just one (non-trivial) von Neumann algebra in $B(H)$ which is clearly impossible.